# Is there an event or method that is called after a NSCollectionViewItem is created to get or set the view controller?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, xamarin, nscollectionview

I want to get a reference to the main applications view controller from inside of NSCollectionViewItem.

I created this function:

```
public partial class MyViewItemController : NSCollectionViewItem {

    private ViewController controller;

    // Called when created from unmanaged code
    public MyViewItemController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) {
        Initialize();
    }

    partial void buttonAction(Foundation.NSObject sender) {
        var button = sender as NSButton;
        controller.performSomething(model);
    }

    private ViewController getController() {
        var localDelegate = CollectionView.Delegate as CollectionViewDelegate;
        var controller = localDelegate.ParentViewController as ViewController;
        return controller;
    }
}
```

But if I call it in the Initialize method it throws an error:

```
    private ViewController controller;

    // Shared initialization code
    void Initialize() {
        controller = getController();// Failed to lookup the required marshalling information.
    }
```

From the error it seems it is too early in the application life cycle to work.

Is there anyway I can get the view controller in the View Item class another way or any other method I can override instead of Initialize() where I can set the controller variable?

Comment: Implement the button action in the main applications view controller and connect the button to the first responder.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to ask your view for its window and from there asking for the mainWindow

```
NSWindow *mainWindow = self.window.mainWindow;
//mainWindow.windowController
//mainWindow.contentViewController
```

you may have to check what class the controllers are for your use case.

Comment: this is because no window no cry.. aka no view.